# How to unlock teclast p80x bootloader?

Tags: fastboot, bootloader-lock

In the Developer menu, I have enabled "Unlock OEM".

I run the following commands in `adb`, and get the following errors:

```
fastboot flashing unlock =

FAILED (remote: 'Not implemet.')

fastboot: error: Command failed

fastboot oem unlook =

FAILED (remote: 'unknown cmd.')

fastboot: error: Command failed

fastboot flash recovery recovery.img =
Sending 'recovery' (14100 KB) OKAY [ 0.599s]
Writing 'recovery' F**AILED (remote: 'Flashing Lock Flag is locked. Please unlock it first!')**
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

[image: fastboot in cmd]

Please help.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm assuming you are referring to this device, http://www.teclast.com/en/zt/P80X; Are there any resources from the manufacturer stating they support this functionality?